# Filtering on table on aspx page

Tags: asp.net, html-table

I need to implement Excel kind of filtering on a table on an aspx page.

What I want is, when I click on any column header it should show me the list of rows in that column with check-box for each one and when I select specific rows then the table should filter accordingly.

Comment: How advanced do you need, and much are you prepared to code yourself?

Comment: I wanted it to do with jquery ... But i could not find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example for one column at a time. I'm working on getting this working for several columns as well: http://jsfiddle.net/mwB37/20/

Since you're asking for a complete plugin with a UI and everything, including relevant code on SO is kinda difficult. But here are the key excerpts that defines my thinking and the concept:

```
// fetching the column index
var columnIndex = th.index();

// then fetching the corresponding TDs (use for-loop when thousands of elements)
var tds = th.closest('table')
            .find('tbody td:nth-child(' + (columnIndex+1) + ')');

// distinctively selecting the unique text values in those columns
var checks = $.unique(tds.map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get());

// the most basic way possible of filtering
// (should be extended into an OR query of all current column filters)
if (index != -1 || arr.length == 0)
    td.parent('tr').show();
else
    td.parent('tr').hide();
```

If you want something already finished instead, this is such a plugin: [PicNet Table Filter](http://www.picnet.com.au/picnet-table-filter.html)

There is also a [filtering](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering) plugin available for the jQuery [DataTables plugin](http://datatables.net/), although sorting is obviously the main focus of that one.

Comment: This is sorting. I was actually looking for filtering. Like I have a column called "Category" and it has data like Car, Lawyer, Pets etc... So now if I click on the column header it should show me the list of all the categories currently in the column and with a check-box and now if I select only Car and Pet it should show only those rows with Car and Pet in the category.

Comment: That can be built using the above techniques. The plugin for jQuery DataTables plugin is filtering, not sorting. Do you mean that you need to disable the sorting functionality alltogether, utilizing only the filtering functionality?

Comment: Yes, for now I only want filtering